# Why do I get same result with different input in openssl_encrypt

Tags: php, encryption

I am trying to encrypt my row data with `openssl_encrypt` in PHP.

I would like to use the same IV for all data in a row (because I want to save just one IV per row). But when I try to encrypt I get the same result for  different inputs when I use a single IV.

For example, I get two variables "username" and "image" and try to encrypt both with one IV but the result returns the same string from the two different inputs (username,image). How can I fix this?

My code:

```
function encrypt($plaintext,$iv): string{

    //echo $iv."\n";
    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
    $ciphertext = base64_encode( $iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw );
    return $ciphertext;
}?>
```

Comment: There is no $key variable in context of the function. run it with all warnings enabled

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny   i know but i want know why two diffrent input with same iv returns equal

Comment: **run it with all warnings enabled** - you will see warning **PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: cipher** and it is the case of identical output. if you replace $cipher with "AES-128-CBC" or add **global $cipher;** into function then you will get different outputs.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny THANKS.i found iv is static variable is it true?

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny and i dont need save iv in somewhere just save key

Comment: what do you mean about "iv is static" ? does _openssl_random_pseudo_bytes_ return the same data for you? there were bugs with implementation of _openssl_random_pseudo_bytes_ in php - it returned the same result in some cases. I do not know whether that issue was fixed. But you can use _random_bytes()_ instead of _openssl_random_pseudo_bytes_ safely

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny same result with random_bytes().my mean when i store encrypted data in one php script . then i can descrypt data from other php script without transfer "iv".i just make "iv" for descrypt with these lines:$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
            $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);